# Can apps script for google sheets send an email to a non Gmail address?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm setting up a google sheet to send an email alert when certain targets are met. It sends fine to my gmail account but it won't send to a non gmail work email group

```
 if (alert == "true"){
        MailApp.sendEmail('group@x.com', subject ,message);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Yes. Perhaps your message is caught as spam. For further help add a [mcve].

Comment: What errors is being returned?

Comment: It's not showing an error, it just doesn't deliver then and instead sends them to my gmail

Answer (score -1):

There is no restriction to send an email from AppsScript to a non Gmail address.

JPA

Comment: Thanks, I presume the issue lie with my companies email system then?